# Get users created on active directory older than 30 days - sharepoint c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

i have a sharepoint 2013 project and i need to create a list of all employees created on active diretory in last 30 days.

What is the best way to do that?

I think that i can do a c# query to active directory using the system.DirectoryServices but because i'm implementing this on a sharepoint farm i dont know if is the best way to do that.

On sharepoint i have the User Profile Service running, so my question is if i can do this with the User Profile Service or use the "old c# way"

Thanks
Flávio

Answer (score 1):

If you run "user profile service synchronization" service, your "user information list" will be uptade. Then you can filter the list by created date. Also you can synch. any AD field with "user information list"
(simple : http://yasingokhanyuksel.blogspot.com.tr/2015/11/sharepoint-survey-add-active-directory.html)

"user information list" is hidden, so type http://yourSiteUrl/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

more information
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list

Answer (score 1):

ygy59 is right about the hidden "user information list" being the only source of a date for a user in SharePoint.  To access it programmatically you would do something like this:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(projURL))
{
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "";
    ListItemCollection items = context.Web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(items);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem item in items)
    {
        DateTime hireDate = (DateTime)item["Created"];
        if(hireDate > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["Name"]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It's important to note that this is the date the item was added to SharePoint and not the day the account was created.  That is something you can control via your server settings though.

Answer (score 0):

Flávio,

When I have created these sorts of solutions for SharePoint environments in the past I have often had to edit them once live to take account of "new requirements" which weren't specified at the beginning.

I would suggest that you architect your solution so that it is simple for the user and or yourself to add extra fields to display, and select by other time periods e.g. new users in past 7 days, new users in past 90 days. OR display firstname, logon, lastname, department, manager, email, phone etc

We did this for one project by allowing specific URL parameters to be used e.g. myreport.aspx?numdays=60&display=firstname,manager,email

Good luck

Dorje

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's user profile service is useful for a lot of things, but I'm not sure it's warranted here (you're not creating audiences, aggregating user information from multiple sources, exposing editable properties, etc.).

Assuming this is an on-premises SharePoint farm coupled with an on-premises Active Directory, I would just hit up Active Directory directly for this information.

As you mentioned, you'll need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices` in your C# code.

```
string subpath = "CN=something, CN=com"; // CNs appropriate to your environment here
string filter = ""; // append additional LDAP filter parameters as necessary

// build LDAP filter query
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
date.AddDays(-30);
string LDAPQuery = "(&(whenCreated>="+date.ToString("YYYYMMdd")+"000000.0Z)" + filter + ")";    

// get DNS host name
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
Object value = entry.NativeObject;
string dnsHostName = entry.Properties["dnsHostName"].value.ToString();

// search Active Directory
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.Filter = LDAPQuery;
searcher.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+dnsHostName+"/"+subpath);
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

// then iterate through results and 
// either display them on a page or create items in a list
```

As Dorje McKinnon mentioned, it's a good idea to make the code flexible enough to accommodate new requirements. I'd parameterize the LDAP query and subpath strings and put them in a SharePoint list somewhere, then have your C# code retrieve them from the SharePoint list before it executes the query.

If this code is going to be run frequently, and if it's only really being used for reporting purposes, you might want to avoid creating SharePoint list items for each of the AD profiles discovered, and instead just show the results on a page, such as in a grid view.